# Lando (docker) always redirect to the same port

Tags: docker, networking, localhost, port, lando

Every application after creation redirect to the same port.

Here is my problem:

I use Lando and every application after creation redirects to the same port.

F.e.

Docker creates app with url http://localhost:32786, but after opening it in browser it redirects me to http://localhost:32797

Also any project that was started and running will be redirected to the same port - 32786.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Pollywaffle yes, but I don't sure what exactly helped :)

As I remember what I trying to do for a fix that problem:

1) Reinstall docker
2) Kill all existing containers

And all my projects were in directory f.e. home/projects/... so I create a new project in a different directory with subdirectories (f.e. home/myprojects/... )

As I remember changing the directory for projects is the way that helps me to fix this issue